# Unity (Unet) Multiplayer Synchronization Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I am working on unity multiplayer.The game is endless runner and the problem is that my character is not synchronizing properly.

[Here is the Screenshot of my unity inspector window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtrgW.png)

Advance thanks for the help

Comment: You have to change network send rate. Network send rate is the number that how much you send data per second.

Comment: You mean that its position is not synchronized properly? Is there some lag or the position is completely wrong?

Comment: @MassimoFrasson there is some lag and also players are spawning at same point (i have empty object with StartPosition component)

Comment: @AqibNawaz If without networking your movement is lag free, I would try to increase Network Sync Rate on NetworkTransform component